# Does Kafka reserve disk space in advance?

Tags: apache-kafka

I have just finished a test-run to see how well my single-node Kafka-cluster (1 Zookeeper, 1 Kafka-Broker) will handle the expected load for a future project. The cluster components are running in Docker-Containers, which are intialized via a docker-compose file.

During the test run, I noticed that the disk utilization didn't go up linearly as I expected. It went up in jumps, although throughput remained constant. This is a graph of the disk usage of the underlying virtual machine (very little else was running on it at the time of the test run, so the VMs disk usage should correlate with that of the broker):

[image: s]

As you can see, there are ever bigger, ever less frequent jumps in disk usage. Also, at the end, the disk usage jumps once more, but drops quite hard after the test run is done.

This leads me to suspect that the Kafka-Broker anticipates expected disk usage and reserves disk space in advance. But I can't seem to find any supporting evidence or documentation on the matter. So, what is happening here?

Comment: I think you should be using volume mounts for the container to the Kafka data directories and measure that

Comment: what did you use to monitor the disk usage?

Comment: @MickaelMaison: that was collectd (specifically, the df plugin) writing the metrics into prometheus. The visualization was done with grafana.

Answer (score 0):

there's a 'log.preallocate' setting in the [broker configs](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#brokerconfigs) that would make kafka pre-create segment files for partitions, but it defaults to false. did you change that setting?

as for the shrink, your log should show if log compaction kicked in or not. you have not mentioned your topic config (was it log compacted?) or your test workload (does it use keys? does it repeat them?) so i cant know for sure.

in my opinion your test workload was simply not producing the data as linearly as you think